# jQuery jScrollPane issue/conflict with Google maps on Safari

Tags: jquery, google-maps, safari, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I seem to have come across a strange bug/conflict between jScrollPane and Google Maps (v3) when viewed on Safari.

The issue is that if I have a LI element inside my scroll Pane, that is set to display:block, and also a google map on the page, the LI element does not scroll with the rest of the content. Removing or simply hiding the google map on the page removes the scrolling issue.

I have built a test case here. 
http://www.incontrolsolutions.com/scroll/stackoverflow.html

This page works correctly in FF, Chrome (Smooth like butter!) and even IE9

But Safari (Including webkit nightly builds up to today) chokes.

Any insight on what can be causing this, or potential workarounds are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Kudos big time for posting that demo complete with the hide/show button and everything.  However, I am unable to reproduce your problem in Safari on either Mac or Windows.  Your demo works fine for me in Safari--everything scrolls as expected no matter what I do. Not sure what to tell you beyond that...

Comment: Thanks Trott, how odd. What version of Safari did you test on?

Comment: Safari 3.2.3 on Windows, and 5.0.5 on Mac OS X.  (Installing Safari 5.0.5 for Windows right now so I can test with that...)

Comment: Works fine in 5.0.5 on Windows for me too.

Comment: OK I posted a mov of what I am seeing. http://www.incontrolsolutions.com/scroll/scroll.mov It seems that the issue is worse when using the scroll wheel, over clicking and dragging the scroll handle..

Comment: Ah, interesting!  I'm on a laptop with no external mouse, so I don't have a scroll wheel to test with right now.  But that might explain why I'm not seeing anything dramatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question and great demo. I can replicate in Safari 5.0.5 on Snow Leopard and it is really strange behaviour.

I have no idea what is causing the problem but it seems like you can work around it by adding a `z-index: 999;` to the CSS rule for `#RS_MapListPanel`. If I make that change through the web inspector then the page seems to behave correctly.

Comment: Vitch! Thanks for that tip! Very odd one for sure but that fixes the problem! Cheers and Thanks!