# Google Maps API killing CSS animations in Safari

Tags: css, google-maps, animation, safari

I have a page with some CSS animations. This page also has a map generated via the Google Maps API.

You can see a stripped down demo here:

http://dev.timmurtaugh.com/demo/projects-map-debug.html

If you click the "Toggle Size" size link *before* hovering over the "Main Nav Item" you will see the toggled element resize as expected.

However, once you hover over the nav element, which should trigger a flyout menu via CSS, not only does the flyout menu not appear, the "Toggle Size" link stops working.

As if this weren't odd enough, the web inspector *thinks* everything is working as normal — it reports that size of the box *is* changing, when visually it is not.

I have tried isolating the map in an iframe, and I get the same results.

This seems to happen only in Safari (5.1.5) / Mac, not in any other browser that I've checked (latest Chrome / Firefox / Internet Explorer 9).

I have tried the suggestions in this question: [jQuery jScrollPane issue/conflict with Google maps on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163975/jquery-jscrollpane-issue-conflict-with-google-maps-on-safari)

... and in this one: [Mac Safari 5.0.4 bug when using Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305680/mac-safari-5-0-4-bug-when-using-google-maps-api)

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: There is a lot of goings on there. After playing around in the inspector, if you change the "-webkit-transition" from ALL to just Opacity (and remove visibility:hidden;) it seems to work in Safari for me. ?

Comment: Could you throw this up on fiddle with absolute links? It would make it super easy to poke :)

Comment: The full template has even more instances of animations that were breaking, and it looks like eliminating the visibility factor has restored all of them to full health.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the over-rides mentioned above (visibility:visible; & -webkit-tranistion:opacity...;) this seems to work for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/vxfhT/1/

Comment: w00! my first SO answer *blush*